# How to get a enum property value by KVC

Tags: swift, key-value-observing

There is a sample like the following:

```
enum Gender{
  case  male
  case  female
}

class Person:NSObject{
   var   name: String?
   var  gender:Gender?
}

let p = Person()
p.name = "A"
p.gender = .male


p.value(forKey:"name")  //A
p.value(forKey:"gender")  //Error: KVO compliant Error
```

How to implement  KVC for enum type property?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you mean KVC (key-value coding), not KVO (key-value observing).

Bother KVC and KVO are an Objective-C NSObject feature. In Swift, you cannot use them except in classes (not enums) that derive from NSObject.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by matt, KVC requires inheritance from NSObject, which is why you're having problems with the `enum`. Depending on your situation, you may be able to use Mirror:

```
enum Gender{
  case  male
  case  female
}

class X {
    var z = Gender.male
}

let x = X()
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: x)
for (name, value) in mirror.children {
    print("\(name)=\(value)")
}
```

This will print the following:

```
Optional("z")=male
```